# JPQL LEFT OUTER JOIN WITH CONDITION

Tags: java, sql, jpa, left-join, jpql

I have query in jpa like this(didnt work):

```
entityManager.createQuery("select new pl.proama.wd.model.PolicyDTO2(pol.policyID) from Policy pol LEFT JOIN pol.claim c  WHERE c.claimID=:id").setParameter("id", "20700003915").getResultList();
```

and database table like this:

**Policy table -->(Policy_id(pk), other colums)**

**Claim table --> (Claim_id(pk),Policy_id,other colums)**

**One policy can join to many claim**

Normal plsql query(work):

```
Select pol.POLICY_ID 
from Policy pol LEFT JOIN CLAIM c 
on(c.POLICY_ID=pol.POLICY_ID) 
WHERE c.CLAIM_ID='20700003915';
```

I think I make mistake in class Policy where I join Claim class.

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "POLICY_ID")
private Claim claim;
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What means `but it didnt work`?

Comment: Didnt return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Move `c.CLAIM_ID` condition from `WHERE` clause to `ON` clause to get true `LEFT JOIN` behavior. (With c condition in the `WHERE` clause, it executes as a regular inner join.)

```
Select pol.POLICY_ID 
from Policy pol LEFT JOIN CLAIM c 
on (c.POLICY_ID=pol.POLICY_ID
    AND c.CLAIM_ID='20700003915');
```

Comment: My plsql query work I have problem with jpql query.

Comment: Do you want LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN? Either adjust to INNER JOIN, or move the c.CLAIM_ID='20700003915' condition!

Comment: It works in SQL but won't work using JPQL. Adding `AND c.CLAIM_ID='20700003915'` condition in **ON** condition list is still not possible.

Comment: @MrASquare - I'm trying to do something similar, adding an AND condition in ON.  I don't get an error instead i get what appears to be the query ignoring the AND.  Is that what you saw?  If so, how did you recommend resolution?

Comment: @SalVelazquez, start your own question instead of as a comment here, and you'll get much better attention!